# Shared Volumes of Rotation around an Axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Can anyone help me figure out how to find the *shared* volume of two rotations of a line, one around the x axis and one around the y? I can't find anything online on the subject, I think the regular integration methods drown out my search attempts.

To keep it simple, say we have a curve $\frac{x^2}{8}$, bound between x=2 and x=8, shown below.

[image]

Revolve it around the x-axis and get a trumpet-like shape, and calculate the volume. Then, revolve it around the y-axis to get maybe a bathroom sink shaped object, I can calculate that too. Now I need to know how to calculate the volume of their shared space, so I can apply it to my problems.

Apparently, it's not that hard (U.K. A level standard) but all the curved edges following curved edges are freaking me out!

Any direction would be appreciated!

W

Comment: To speak meaningfully about either of these volumes, you must specify other bounds besides the one curve.

Comment: The region you have drawn  is bounded between $x=2$, $x=8$, $y=\dfrac{x^2}{8}$ and $y=0$. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Here is a desmos graph indicating the two solids: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eft7ureigm

Comment: Apologies, I missed out the bounds in the x axis, it was late at night for me. Good Desmos skills! I think this is what I'm looking for though Rory might have a point. The questions u have don't specify if it's above or below the line for the y rotation and I don't know the standard.

Comment: *"the questions I have"  (typo).

Answer (score 1):

From your description I believe you are rotating only the curve itself, as defined for $2\le x\le 8$, and not the area under the curve shaded in your graphic. That is the straightforward conclusion from your words and one aspect of your graphic (the bounds on $x$)--if that understanding is wrong, explain in detail just what you mean.

Given your two state rotations, the only intersection between those rotated volumes is the curve itself, which has volume zero. Therefore, the shared volume is zero.

To see the intersection, when rotating around the $x$-axis you use the area *below* the curve down to the $x$-axis. When rotating around the $y$-axis you use the area *above* and to the left of the curve.

Comment: Going along with your line of thinking, then there is no volume in either of the rotations anyway. It's just two surfaces. If it were anything else it would appear to be a very difficult problem.

Comment: My first answer was that! At first I thought they don't share a volume, one is below the curve, one is above,  but then I thought I had it wrong and I was looking at the trumpet / sink objects and where they overlap (John's Desmos shows well what I am thinking). Is there a standard? How do I know if the volume I need to find is above or below the curve? The question gives an equation and 2 bounds on the x axis. Maybe the question isn't written so well and assumes too much.